# Can't install tensorflow in R, my machine is 64 bit but R doesn't detect it

Tags: r, tensorflow, installation, 64-bit

I'm using windows, my problem is that while trying to install tensorflow in R the following error message appears.

Error in install_tensorflow(method = method, conda = conda, version = tensorflow,  : 
  Unable to install TensorFlow on this platform.Binary installation is only available for 64-bit platforms.

My machine is 64 bit, so I don't understand where is the problem.
I've already cheked if my anaconda installation and the python version are 64bit and they are.

I can install tensorflow in python without any error, but i can't in R.

I've tried to redirect the R tensorflow installation to the python environment but i don't know if it can really help.

```
> library(tensorflow)
> install_tensorflow()
Error in install_tensorflow() : 
  Unable to install TensorFlow on this platform.Binary installation is only available for 64-bit platforms.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to install older version of tensorflow which is 1.5.0 using command pip install tensorflow==1.5.0

Comment: I had same issue so installed older version of tensorflow, may be it was because of old hardware at my side.

Comment: I did it for python, may be it will work for R also